# Understanding and Writing Parsers

Tags: parsing

I'm writing a program that requires me to create my first real, somewhat complicated parser. I would like to understand what parsing algorithms exists, as well as how to create a "grammar". So my question(s) are as follows:

1) How does one create a formal grammar that a parser can understand? What are the basic components of a grammar?

2) What parsing algorithms exists, and what kind of input does each exceed at parsing?

3) In light of the broad nature of the questions above, what are some good references I can read through to understand the answer to questions 1 and 2?

I'm looking for more of a broad overview with the keywords/topic areas I need so I can look into the details myself. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Like you said, it's very broad so it's not really suitable here. Nor is asking for references outside SO. There is a lot of material available with a quick search.

Comment: Taking a less scientific and more engineering approach, see [Comparison of parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators). Many of those parsers have communities here on Stack Overflow; Search for their tags. Also, there are [internal Domain-Specific Languages](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally write a **context-free grammar** `G` that describes a certain **formal language** `L` (e.g. the set of all syntactically valid C programs) which is simply a set of strings over a certain alphabet (think of all well-formed C programs; or of all well-formed HTML documents; or of all well-formed MARKDOWN posts; all of these are sets of finite strings over certain subsets of the ASCII character set). After that you come up with a **parser** for the given grammar---that is, an algorithm that, given a string `w`, decides whether the string `w` can be derived by the grammar `G`. (For example, the [grammar of the C11 language](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) describes the set of all well-formed C programs.)

Some types of grammars admit simple-to-implement parsers. An example of grammars that are often used in practice are [LL grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar). A special subset of `LL` grammars, called the `LL(1)` grammars, have parsers that run in linear time (linear in the length of the string we're parsing).

There are more general parsing algorithms---most notably the [Early parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) and the [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm)---that take as inpuit a string `w` and a grammar `G` and decide in time `O(|w|^3)` whether the string `w` is derivable by the grammar `G`. (Notice how cool this is: the algorithm takes the grammar as an agrument. But I don't think this is used in practice.)

I implemented the Early parser in Java some time ago. If your're insterested, the code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/blazs/algorithms-2014/tree/master/seminar-3).

For a concrete example of the whole process, consider the language of all balanced strings of parenthesis `()`, `(())`, `((()))()(())()`, etc. We can describe them with the following context-free grammar:

```
S -> (S) | SS | eps
```

where `eps` is the empty production. For example, we can derive the string `(())()` as follows: `S => SS => (S)S => ((S))S => (())S => (())(S) => (())()`. We can easily implement a parser for this grammar (left as exercise :-).

A very good references is the so-called dragon book: [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) by Aho et al. It covers all the essential topics. Another good reference is the classic book [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html)  by Hopcroft et al.